# Issue while using python rss feed with feedparser

Tags: python, rss, python-3.7, feedparser

I am trying to get the data from a rss feed using python 3.7.7 and feedparser.

I am able to get the simple information like feed['title'] but I am unable to get feed['ht:approx_traffic'] which is one of the tags that I want.

```
import feedparser

def getFeed():
    feed = feedparser.parse('https://trends.google.com/trends/trendingsearches/daily/rss?geo=US')
    for post in feed.entries:  
        print(post['title']) // works
        print(post['ht:approx_traffic']) // error


getFeed()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key that you're looking for is `ht_approx_traffic` not `ht:approx_traffic`.

You can see the list of keys with

```
print(post.keys())
```